# How can I create a PaperDisk?

Tags: storage, paper

How could I create a PaperDisk?

Just found the [website of PaperDisk](http://www.paperdisk.com/), but no software for creation and reading of those.

Comment: But why would you want to do that?

Comment: because storing data is much more reliable than a cd or else. Ink lasts for a very long time

Comment: Are you building a data vault in case the technological civilization collapses?

Comment: No not really. But who knows. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working alternative: [PaperBa(c)k](http://www.ollydbg.de/Paperbak/index.html)

> PaperBack is a free application that allows you to back up your precious files on the ordinary paper in the form of the oversized bitmaps. If you have a good laser printer with the 600 dpi resolution, you can save up to 500,000 bytes of uncompressed data on the single A4/Letter sheet. Integrated packer allows for much better data density - up to 3,000,000+ (three megabytes) of C code per page.